# Any command in C++ called script ();

Tags: c++

I am new to C++ and I am trying to understand a part of code and i am stuck here

```
try {
    Result = Script(ArgStr);
}
```

Is this come command in C++ .. if i go tolook where is this defined... it says

```
virtual bool Script(CString ArgStr) = 0;
```

I am confused about this part....

I would appreciate for your help in this regards,

Comment: I think you skipped the first 7 or so chapters of the tutorial.

Comment: Two points. There are no "commands" in C++, there are statements, definitions, declarations, standard library functions and other stuff. And also C++ is a case sensitive language so you shouldn't write "script" in the title and then posting code that uses "Script". These two could be very different things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not part of normal C++.  It looks like it's a member function call called "Script" from the same class you are working in.  It's argument type is a single `CString` and returns a boolean value.  The variable `Result` is just that, a variable and is instantiated elsewhere but assigned within the try-catch block you've shown us.  You might be confused by the fact that the variable name within the argument declaration is the same as the variable named passed into it in this case.  It is not.  It just happens to have the same name.

Comment: I looked at the definition for Script ( in VS 6.0 ) and It refers to various class function definitions like connect::Script(CString ArgStr ) , test::script(CString ArgStr)... I was wondering that because it is defined as virtual..? also when i refer back to it Script name changes to Declare_Connect_Script(CString ArgStr) and so on...

Comment: Ok I forgot to look at this portion of the code...:)                          #define DECLARE_TEST_SCRIPT(name) \
class name : CTestScript {\
public:\
  name(const char *pScriptName) : CTestScript(pScriptName) {}\
  bool Script(CString ArgStr);\
}; name name(#name); bool name::Script(CString ArgStr)\

Answer (score 2):

No there is no such command. You are just calling a function called `Script`

Answer (score 1):

Script() is a pure virtual function existing in(most probably) a base class taking a CString as it's parameter and returning a boolean value. You should read the entire code to understand what it does.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming Script() is defined in a Class named A:
Something like this

```
class A
{
    virtual bool Script(CString ArgStr) = 0; //this is a pure virtual function
}
```

You should look for Classes that inherit A. i.e. Classes that are derived from A.
Since Script() is defined as pure virtual, u will only find its Definition in a derived class.